# How is WPF startup with App.xaml/cs and MainWindow.xaml/cs

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose we start from the default new WPF project with `App.xaml/cs`, `MainWindow.xaml/cs`.
What's the order the application execute these codes.

1. Parse `App.xaml`
2. Run `App.xaml.cs`
3. Parse `MainWindow.xaml`
4. Run `MainWindow.xaml.cs`?

And how about the execution of `Resource.Designer.cs` and `Settings.Designer.cs` in Properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every .NET application (PE files) start with an entry point which is generally "`Main`" but in WPF you can't see this because Visual Studio hides it from the user as it is quite messy code.

You'll know yourself the execution flow once you find the `Main` method. For that look at the following image:

[image: WPF project tree]

Comment: btw, whats the different between *.g.cs and *.g.i.cs?

Comment: I think g.ic.cs is a template for generating g.cs. But Not sure. Maybe you could find and write your solution here :)

Answer (score 2):

As Int3 user says, the Main method is located at App.g.cs and goes like this

```
public static void Main() {
    YourAppNamespace.App app = new YourAppNamespace.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

Which means you'll get the App constructor executed before anything else.